# String-copying function results in `pointer being freed was not allocated`

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, deep-copy

I have the following function:

```
void stringcopy(char * to, char const * const from)
{
    int size = 1;
    while (from[size] != '\0') { ++size; }

    if (to != 0) { delete [] to; }
    to = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { to[i] = from[i]; }
}
```

As the name notes, it copies a string, using dynamic allocation.

---

I don't believe the way I use it ought to matter (as I'm trying to make this function robust), but here are some examples:

```
CD::CD(char * s1, char * s2, int n, double x)
{
    stringcopy(performers, s1);
    stringcopy(label, s2);
    selections = n;
    playtime = x;
}
```

and

```
CD::CD(const CD & d)
{
    stringcopy(performers, d.performers);
    stringcopy(label, d.label);
    selections = d.selections;
    playtime = d.playtime;
}
```

etc.

---

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message, when I use the function: `pointer being freed was not allocated`.

I assume it occurs do to `if (to != 0) { delete [] to; }`.

---

**Why doesn't this line protect against deallocating non-allocated memory?**

Comment: `to` is local to `stringcopy()`.  In order to enable the caller's (pointer) value to be modified, you must pass it by reference or pass a pointer to it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- Aren't I by using `char *`? Or, do I have to use a double pointer?

Comment: You are passing a `char *` by value.  `stringcopy()` can use its copy of that pointer value to modify the `char`, if any, to which it points, but it cannot modify the caller's copy of the pointer, which is what you need to do.  So as I said, you need to pass the pointer by reference, or else pass a pointer to it (i.e. a `char **`).

Comment: Implementing strings at all well is somewhat tricky, and (more importantly) pretty much a solved problem. Do you have a spectacularly good reason to do this yourself instead of using `std::string`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin -- I'm a student learning C++; so, in addition to learning algorithms such as this, why not practice C++ at the same time? `:)`

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- OK, thanks. As commented on an answer below, what changes do I make to use a reference?

Comment: Practicing C++ at the same time *can* be sort of all right. But, if you decide to reinvent every wheel in sight, it can be difficult to make much progress, simply because it's hard to concentrate on one part of your code when many parts are at least partially broken (and you're never quite sure which parts really work, and which don't). Also, if you're going to reinvent a wheel, it's better to at least have some notion of what existing wheels look like, so yours is at least close to round.

Comment: @JerryCoffin -- Well, it's an exercise from a textbook. Plus, I need to practice somehow, right? `:)`

Comment: @SirJony To use reference to pointer, You need to change signature of function like `void stringcopy(char *& to, char const * const from)`. Now, Whatever you will do with `to` will be reflected at caller's space!

Comment: And also you need to make sure that both buffers pointed by `to` and `from` contain valid value (i.e. initialized already before we invoke stringcopy() function).

Comment: @PravarJawalekar -- They aren't initialized yet. That's why I have `if (to != 0)`, so when it isn't initialized it skips the deallocation. However, it doesn't seem to work. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @SirJony OK. So what problem now you are facing after you changed code to use reference-to-pointer (i.e. *&) ? Or same error you are facing as mentioned in original question? Please edit question if there are different errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here

```
if (to != 0) { delete [] to; }
to = new char[size];
```

is freeing the memory to which the local `to` variable points, allocating it newly and storing the string there.

This new local memory address (let's call it `to1`) is however never exposed to the outside world, as it's not returned from the function. The function get's a **copy** of the `to` address. In order to fix that you need to make `to` a double pointer. Or a reference to a pointer.

Comment: So, in addition to changing the definition to `char * & to`, what else do I change?

Comment: should be ok then

Comment: My compiler tells me otherwise. `:)` Do I change anything within the block?

Comment: Then it depends on the use of the function. Maybe you are passing an unitialized variable (e.g. performers) to it, which is default initialized to 0, and so delete is called on it?

Comment: Yes, it is uninitialized initially. This function doubles as the initializer (hence `to = new char[size];`) Why would delete be called on it?

Comment: YOU have a variable called performers in your example